# Layout issue with ScrollView & table

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, material-design

I have a form using ScrollView. There are 2 spinners in the form and in portrait mode one of spinners goes out of the screen but in landscape view the spinner is visible. What setting needs to be changed so that spinner does not go out of the screen? (Comment- The label Select Month in the image should actually be "Select Month & Year" )

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp">
<!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
-->

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp">
        <!--Month Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Month & Year"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinneryr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field1 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ERYTHROCYTE"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ERYTHROCYTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field2 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/HAEMOGLOBIN"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/HAEMOGLOBIN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field3 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PCV"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PCV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field4 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/RDW"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/RDW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field5 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCV"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field6 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCH"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCH"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>

        <!--Field7 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCHC"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCHC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field8 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LEUCOCYTECOUNT"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LEUCOCYTECOUNT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field9 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PLATELETS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PLATELETS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field10 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NEUTROPHILS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/NEUTROPHILS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field11 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/EOSINOPHILS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EOSINOPHILS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field12 Combo Box-->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LYMPHOCYTES"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LYMPHOCYTES"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!-- Button :Start here-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnViewAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_all" />
        </TableRow>

            <!--<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/delete" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnShowInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/show_info" />
        </TableRow>-->

<!--        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnModify"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/modify" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view" />




           <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/show_info" >
        </TableRow-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvValues"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I accept Marcin Orlowski's suggestion and I think it is the correct way to implement.

Answer (score 2):

> What setting needs to be changed so that spinner does not go out of the screen?

None. There's no settings for that - it's basically how you made your layout and it simply does not fit. You can consider having separate layout file for each orientation so you'd i.e. put spinners vertically for portrait layout -> just create `layout-land` in your `res/` and copy current layout there. Then edit the one in `layout` to make it better fit the screen. That's it.

Comment: Thank you Sir.Your answer makes sense and I will implement it. One more question, this layout design worked fine with SDK 23 before I recompiled the application to work with SDK 25. Is that possible or am I wrong?

Comment: that's actually a better way to solve this issue! .. And @Ajay : it's not abt sdk versions, it's just that the Table Layout works in that way! it's better to work the way Marvin advised. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting answer to my question. I managed to fix the issue by doing the following changes to ScrollView. After the change the TextView & both spinners are now visible on the same row and well aligned.

```
Code changes to ScrollView -
    1) Updating android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    2) Updating android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    3) Adding android:fillViewport="true"
Code changes to TableLayout 
    1) Added android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    2) Added android:gravity="center"
```

Solution suggested by @Marcin is another way (probably a more versatile solution) to solve the issue but since the above solution worked I did not try it.